# How to formally verify correctness of vectorized C code (or Fortran)

Tags: c, vectorization, avx, frama-c, formal-verification

I'm trying to use Frama-c but I want to use AVX instructions in some places. Noramlly you can enable them with `gcc -mavx2`. Is there something like this for Frama-C. If not, is there some better tool for this? Perhaps it would be easier to verify Fortran code as it abstracts vectorization details but I am not aware of any tools for verifying Fortran code.

Comment: You will need to write contracts for AVX intrinsics and use them to proof properties of your program.

Comment: (Stack Overflow's limit of 5 tags really sucks sometimes.  This question could use about 8, including also [simd], and [intrinsics] if you're talking about manually vectorized code using `_mm256_permutexvar_epi32` (`vpermd`) and so on.  I dropped [fortran] in favour of [formal-verification] since that's the crux of the whole thing.  Perhaps dropping [avx] would make more sense.)

Comment: You should open an issue on https://git.frama-c.com/pub/frama-c . I started to work on such a support for SSE some time ago (didn't have time to continue though ...). The good news is that I believe there is no need for any modification in Frama-C kernel for basic support (just to write a libc with some models of the behavior of the registers). But there are *a lot* of intrinsics (reason why I stopped working on it without use case to support). Depending on which kind of verification you are interested in however, it might need new features in Frama-C plugins.